# US 30 day Visa requirements from Indonesia?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, indonesia

So my girlfriend is from Indonesia, and according to her she went to a US embassy some years ago before we even met and tried to visit the US on a vacation. They gave her a list of documents to bring like a birth certificate, proof of where she was employed, etc and that she had to have $10,000 in her bank account to prove she could support herself for the trip.

There's a noticeable difference in the value of USD and IDR so she of course didn't have enough at the time and they rejected her application. I'm wondering however if she could prove other means of financial stability for her trip. Maybe prove she's dating a US citizen and that I'll be accommodating her.

After Googling I didn't find anything about a required bank balance or anything like it. So I'm not sure where to look.

Any info would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: We've been dating for 2 years and I've already visited her in Indonesia for two weeks. She's said multiple times she doesn't want to come to America because how unfriendly it can be to muslims. I'm not going to give her $10,000 I don't even have that much in my account. It would make sense to me that she would need to prove financial stability of some sort for her trip. Looks like I'm not finding the answer here. I'll just have to call the embassy I guess.

Comment: Be careful how you present your relationship if you're planning to offer yourself as sponsor. It's not a big leap to the idea that your girlfriend is trying to immigrate to the US, and once US immigration get that idea then she'll find it much harder to get a visa at all.

Comment: See https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html for general information on visit visa requirements. And here https://help.cbp.gov/ci/fattach/get/73503/0/filename/Status+and+Intentions-Strong+Ties.pdf for examples of how to satisfy status and non-immigrant intent requirements. The story about $10,000 sounds like local lore based on eg ‘knowing someone who knows someone who says...’ rather than fact. If you want to find out for sure, try completing an application, and ask your girlfriend to show you the refusal letter from her first application

Comment: _**and that she had to have $10,000 in her bank account to prove she could support herself for the trip**_ A total fabrication.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus "Total fabrication" implies a deliberate lie, which is unlikely in this case. Please be careful with your wording.

Comment: Since it is established that this may not be a potential scam, answering with the official requirements of a US non-immigrant visa would be good. Voting to leave open for now.

Comment: @Edward Severinsen There is an example of a completed DS-160 application form here https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/PDF-other/DS-160_Example.pdf There is no mention of a $10,000 requirement, nor is this stated anywhere on the website of the US Embassy in Manila http://www.ustraveldocs.com/ph/ph-niv-appointmentschedule.asp

Comment: There is no such requirement to have the equivalent of USD 10000 in a bank account, nor any specific amount of money. The requirement is that the visa applicant must demonstrate that they do not intend to immigrate illegally to the USA and have sufficient financial support for the length of their visit. It is possible for someone even with no money to do this, e.g. through family ties, sponsorship by someone else, etc.

Comment: I'm a 19 year old out of high school about to go into the military. I assure you, she's not with me for my money. 2 years seems like an awfully long time to lead someone on for $10,000. And we Skype all day, if this is an act then she deserves an award because it's pretty convincing. She even had to send me $200 to help me get a ticket to visit her. And she didn't even harvest my organs.